# SQL: Combining Count from one table

Tags: sql

Currently, my SQL Query is:

```
SELECT PAT_TYPE, COUNT(*) AS "# OF PATRONS"
FROM PATRON
GROUP BY PAT_TYPE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Output:
 
[image]

Now I need to rewrite the Query to display only two rows of "Student" and "Faculty".  Such as this output:
[image]

I've been really stuck on this one.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: tried LIMIT 2 ?

Comment: SELECT PAT_TYPE, sum(COUNT(*)) AS "# OF PATRONS"
    FROM PATRON
    GROUP BY PAT_TYPE;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uppercase the patron column:

```
SELECT UPPER(PAT_TYPE), COUNT(*) AS "# OF PATRONS"
FROM PATRON
GROUP BY UPPER(PAT_TYPE)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

You might want to make it a point to store your faculty names in the same case or at least format.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about that! 

Thanks a lot.